# Firebase function storage POST image issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have encountered a problem when following a maximilian schwarzmüller course, which has otherwise been great: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ1EFnFOGvE

The image logs in the Firebase console as uploaded, recognises the type of file/size etc. But continually loads and never displays the image. I use a post request in POSTMAN to upload the image.
When I upload manually to firebase on their UI, everything works fine.

My code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");
const spawn = require("child-process-promise").spawn;
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const Busboy = require("busboy");
const fs = require("fs");



const gcconfig = {
  projectId: "REDACTED",
  keyFilename: "REDACTED"
};

const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")(gcconfig);

//
exports.onFileChange = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(event => {
  const object = event.data;
  const bucket = object.bucket;
  const contentType = object.contentType;
  const filePath = object.name;
  console.log("File change detected, function execution started");

  if (object.resourceState === "not_exists") {
    console.log("We deleted a file, exit...");
    return;
  }

  if (path.basename(filePath).startsWith("resized-")) {
    console.log("We already renamed that file!");
    return;
  }

  const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);
  const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
  const metadata = { contentType: contentType };
  return destBucket
    .file(filePath)
    .download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
    })
    .then(() => {
      return spawn("convert", [tmpFilePath, "-resize", "500x500", tmpFilePath]);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return destBucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
        destination: "resized-" + path.basename(filePath),
        metadata: metadata
      });
    });
});

exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: "Not allowed"
      });
    }
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let uploadData = null;

    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
      uploadData = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    });

    busboy.on("finish", () => {
      const bucket = gcs.bucket("REDACTED");
      bucket
        .upload(uploadData.file, {
          uploadType: "media",
          metadata: {
            metadata: {
              contentType: uploadData.type
            }
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "It worked!"
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: err
          });
        });
    });
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
  });
});
```

My security rules:

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service firebase.storage { 
  match /b/{bucket}/o { 
    match /{allPaths=**} { 
      allow read, write:if true; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write:if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: What if you use [busboy-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy-promise) instead? Please watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ for more info on why it may be better to use Promises.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I very much like that video series. I was just wondering why this method does not work.

Comment: In the vdeo series you see why it is of upmost importance to manage the asynchronous tasks through Promises. This is why I would better use a "promisified" version of busboy.

Comment: I really do understand where you're coming from, I just don't know why this method doesn't work for me but works for other people!